# ESCPOS-PHP Printer Library Status Catch

Tags: php, printing

Am using the Mike42\Escpos\Printer PHP library for printing over the network and I want to catch the printer status if it's out of paper or on offline mode, on basis of this status I want to update in a database or alert the user that the printer is out of paper. Is there any idea how can we catch this?

Comment: Hi Megha, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? It looks like there are a few useful examples on the https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php site to get started.

Comment: Hi @Liam i have tried everything except i want to get the printer status, like rolled out of paper, so if printer has no paper then i will apply some conditions